# How to do I fix a JNI issue for Jar file?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij IDE and I managed to produce a JAR file, but when I try running it won't work. I have tried to reinstall the newest JDK but that hasn't worked either.
This is what I am trying to run:

```
java -jar Ex4.jar
```

This is what I keep getting:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Ex4/Ex4 has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 59.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

Comment: It appears that you're trying to use a Java 8 runtime for a Java 15 compiled artifact. Try `java --version`. Either set the project Java version in IntelliJ to 8  or bump your runtime version.

Comment: _I have tried to reinstall the newest JDK_ I assume you mean JDK 15. It appears that you have not succeeded. In the same way that you enter the command `java -jar Ex4.jar` try entering the command `java -version`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time! I have tried changing on Intellij the version, it seems the lowest version is 11. I might not know what I am doing as I am new to coding and new to Intellij

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve my issue:

1. Enter Settings [Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCEoT.png)
2. Press arrow down on build [open the arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dL7sh.png)
3. Press arrow down on compiler [open the arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WICOL.png)
4. press on Java compiler  [press on Java Compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIqi1.png)
5. Choose the version that suits your JRE [choose which version u need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69evn.png)